# How to show file upload or download progress on richtextbox windows form c#

Tags: c#, progress-bar, richtextbox

i want to design UI like when user drag or drop any file on rich textbox then a progress bar should be shown on richtextbox for showing progress of file upload and download. i am not being able to show progress bar on richtextbox. so any one can guide me how to show progressbar on richtextbox? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out, maybe you can insert an OLE object into your RichTextBox. This is old school, but it surely works:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12135/Inserting-images-into-a-RichTextBox-control-the-OL

Good luck!

Comment: i do not like to use OLE...rather give me some other solution.i hope u have seen or use skype. when people drag any file onto skype textbox then a progressbar come....i just need to simulate something like that.here i am giving a image link just click on it and then u can understand how things should look like.can u give me any idea

Comment: I don't see any image link. You can try drawing a progress bar in top of your RTB using the drawing primitives, it shouldn't be too difficult since a progress bar is just a rectangle filled with some color.

Comment: here is the image link just have look....http://i.stack.imgur.com/5oRkt.png i want to show peogress bar this way on richtextbox. thanks

Comment: Are you sure Skype actually uses a RichTextBox and not a WebBrowser? Have you spied into the Skype Window?

Comment: Here, I did it for you. Skype actually uses a control called "TChatContentControl" which I imagine is their custom ChatBox control. Maybe Google "TChatContentControl" and see if you find something.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best solution would be to superimpose a progress bar over the top of the RichTextBox and Hide/Show at the point you want the bar to be displayed.

Comment: thanks for answer.can u guide me....just giving me some code...i am not being able to understand how to do it.

Comment: i hope u have seen or use skype. when people drag any file onto skype textbox then a progressbar come....i just need to simulate something like that.here i am giving a image link just click on it and then u can understand how things should look like.can u give me any idea

Comment: here is the image link just have look....http://i.stack.imgur.com/5oRkt.png i want to show peogress bar this way on richtextbox. thanks

Answer (score 0):

alternative way but more simple: show progress in text like "*Step Performed 12.25% ...*" and replace percentage part on progress.